# Need Query - Row count with loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a Primary table like

```
========================================
ID    NAME    logtime (date time colum) 
========================================
1     cat     dd/mm/yyyy 10.30

2     cat   dd/mm/yyyy 9.20

3     cat    dd/mm/yyyy 9.30

4     cat   dd/mm/yyyy 7.20
```

Secondary Table like

```
---------------------
Name     improvement
---------------------
cat       1
```

Now I want to create a loop

To calculate difference between first 2 rows, if the difference is >= 1 hr then update the secondary table as **existing value +1**(that is 2) else rest it.

Now calculate 2'nd and 3'rd rows,
To calculate difference between first 2 rows, if the difference is >= 1 hr then update the secondary table as **existing value +1**, here the answer is 2.

Then 3'rd and 4'th.
Once all row are calculated then exit from the loop.

can anyone give me a query for this?

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service. You should edit your question to show what you've tried and what you're stuck on.

Comment: Also, what version of sql server are you working with?

Comment: sql server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    declare @timediff table(id int identity(1,1),Name varchar(50),logtime datetime)
    insert into @timediff Select Name,logtime from timediff

   declare @datetimeDiff int
   declare @i int=1
   while(@i<=(Select count(*) from @timediff))
     Begin
         Select @datetimeDiff=datediff(hour,logtime,
         (Select logtime from  @timediff where id=@i+1)) 
         from @timediff  where id=@i
         if(@datetimeDiff>=1)
         BEGIN
         Select @datetimeDiff
         --You can write your update code here

        END


        Set @i=@i+2
      END
```